# Couldn't find Course without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to access app/views/companies/courses/show.html.erb(which is redirected after app/views/companies/courses/new.html.erb), rails server says that it cannot find a course without an ID.

Also, when I run Course.all on rails console, the courses have the correct id, the correct description and the correct company id but no name attribute.

App/controllers/companies/courses_controller:

```
class Companies::CoursesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_company!

  def new
    @course = Course.new
  end

  def create
    @course = current_company.courses.create(course_params)
    if @course.save
      redirect_to companycourse_path(:course => @course.id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @course = current_company.courses.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @courses = current_company.courses.all
  end

  private

  def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

App/models/course.rb:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

App/models/company.rb:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :courses
end
```

Config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :companies
  devise_for :users
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
  resources :users, only: [:show]
  get 'companies/:id' => 'companies#show'
  resources :companies, only: [:show] do
    resources :courses, only: [:show,:new,:create,:index]
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'signup', to: 'users/registrations#new'
    get 'login', to: 'users/sessions#new'
  end

  devise_scope :company do
    get 'companysignup', to: 'companies/registrations#new'
    get 'companylogin', to: 'companies/sessions#new'
    get 'newcourse', to:'companies/courses#new'
    post 'newcourse', to:'companies/courses#create'
    get 'companycourse', to:'companies/courses#show'
    get 'companycoursesindex', to:'companies/courses#index'
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you passing an id?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing an id when redirecting from new to show:

Comment: redirect_to companycourse_path(:course => @course.id)

Comment: @iceman, I tried your suggestion and now I have the same error on a different line:

Comment: @course = current_company.courses.find(params[:id])

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem building my app not long ago and my problem was coming from controllers.

In your routes.rb I would add `resources :companies, :has_many => :courses`.I also would add a validation to your course model in models/course.rb to make sure that when you save it to the database your object has a title: `class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company validates :title, presence: :true 
end`

Also try using this or something along lines in your courses_controller.rb instead of your current code:

```
    def create
     @company = find_company
     @course = Course.new(course_params)
     @course.company_id = current_company.id
    if @course.save
     your conditions here
    else
     your conditiona here
    end
   end 

   private
    def find_company
     params.each do |name, value|
      if name == 'company_id'
        return @company = Company.find(value.to_i)
      end
     end
    nil
    end
```

I hope it helps.